# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Django - What happens first when deploying to EB, pip install -r requirements.txt or commands in configuration file

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, python-imaging-library, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying to the Elastic Beanstalk, in what order are all the dependencies installed? For one part, I have all my project dependencies in requirements.txt. This includes `PIL`. But for `PIL` I need to install libjpeg and other libraries as such (this is in .ebextensions/myapp.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    libjpeg-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []

... rest of config file
```

Only problem is, if pip is run first, I would have to reinstall Pillow which I do not know how to do

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) mentions that the Packages section is processed first.

> The order in which these are processed are as follows:
>
> 1. Packages
> 2. Files
> 3. Commands
> 4. Services
> 5. Container Commands